# Domain redirirection to https issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have an issue with my domain redirections. 
It's wordpress and I want to redirect all non secure urls to secure

The problem that when typing in the addressbar: http://www.my-domain.com it redirects to https://www.www.my-domain.com
(It adds an extra www)

Here is my redirection part in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: _You_ are adding the extra www: `RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]` - `%1` is the matched host name, and that was `www.my-domain.com` already.

Answer (score 0):

This code is Work for me

```
     # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteOptions inherit
    RewriteEngine on
    Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```